# Hosting asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, hosting

I want to host same asp.net application on 2 different servers under 2 different domain names. This is for a back-up in case one of the servers malfunction. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's possible.  The trick is to ensure that the data stays synchronized, which is not an easy task going across domains.

A better approach might be to use Clustering.  It's more of a Network Administrator's task than a developer task (so this might be beter answered on ServerFault.com), but yes, it can be done.

Some articles on Clustering:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687537.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742600.aspx

http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2009/10/27/iis7-and-failover-clustering.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Setup one domain name as a CNAME for the other. Then run the two servers as a redundant cluster.

There are things to consider in the app though: do you use sticky sessions so that a user with a session on one server is always served by the same one until the session expires or can you rewrite the app to avoid session variables or add some mechanism to synchronise between them...

[Microsoft Support:HOW TO: Set Up Multi-Server ASP.NET Web Applications and Web Services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815162)